# How can I set a background image to scroll with scrolling content?

Tags: html, css

```
<div>Content</div>

div{width:100px;height:100px;background:url('../images/image.gif') fixed repeat;overflow:auto;}
```

The text within the dev scrolls over the background, how do I make the content scroll with the content. (assuming the content extends below the bottom of the div)?

Does that make sense?

Edit: I want the background image to move with the content when its scrolled down.

The background image should move upwards with the content as you scroll down the div.

Comment: Make the content scroll with the content...?

Comment: Could you make a http://jsfiddle.net so that we can actually see your example in use.

Comment: I could except I cant create what I want to see.. hence the problem. the example is exactly how it appears.

And JSfiddle is not loading for me atm, attributed no doubt to the appalling NZ internet service. >:(

Comment: I wouldn't ask you to create a fiddle answering your own question. I just meant could you create one that looks exactly how you are starting off, so that the incorrect scrolling is visible etc.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `fixed` from your background declaration. Is that what you mean by scrolling with the content?

```
div { width:100px; height:100px; background:url('../images/image.gif') repeat; }
```

Comment: No. That is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:url('../images/image.gif') repeat scroll center top transparent;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the different blocks of background (background-image, etc.)